# Android Fade In/Out animation from bottom to top

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am creating a animation in which I want to fade out my imageview but the fading animation should start from bottom to top unlike fading animation in which whole imageview fades at once.

```
public void animateFadeIn() {
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
    motherboard.startAnimation(in);
    motherboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    in.setDuration(1500);
    in.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animateFadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

How to achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:fromYScale="-450"
    android:toYScale="450" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Comment: follow this link it can help you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: paste your animation.xml files

Comment: @NileshRathod I am simply using default android animation xml. 
** android.R.anim.fade_in** & ** android.R.anim.fade_out**

Comment: than please creat your custom animation

Comment: @NileshRathod I exactly don't know in what direct to proceed in order to create fade out animation from bottom to top

Answer (score 2):

create a slide_up.xml in your

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="75%p"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

your fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

   <alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

than load animation

```
ImageView imageview;
Animation animFadein, animslideup;

animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_in);
    animslideup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_up);

 final AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(true);
    s.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    s.addAnimation(animslideup);
    s.addAnimation(animFadein);
    imageview.startAnimation(s);
```

Comment: the image is animating fine through your above code. But one thing that I really want to achieve is when animation starts, the image starts to fade out from bottom and then fades out till the top. Can you please please help me out with this

Comment: the images is not disappearing with fading effect. It is simply disappearing with slide from bottom to top.
I want to achieve animation similar to [Cooling Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easyx.coolermaster)  
Image Number -2

Comment: could you please help me out with this

Comment: yes I have tried it. 
After using the above code, the image is disappearing from bottom to top with translation animation. 
not with the fading animation